# SMTP server response: 501 <>: missing or malformed local part

Tags: php, email, smtp

I am using mime_mailer.php to send emails. When I send email it shows the following error:

```
Warning:    mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 501 <>: missing or malformed local part
Script:     /ppm/lm_response.php
File:   mime_mailer.php
Line:   33
Time:   2012-05-08 23:55:50 (PDT)
Warning:    Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\xampp\htdocs\ppm\common.php:275)
Script:     /ppm/lm_response.php
File:   lm_response.php
Line:   44
Time:   2012-05-08 23:55:50 (PDT)
```

Header looks something likes this:

```
To: abc@ourdomain.com
From: def@ourdomain.com
X-Mailer: PHP/5.2.9 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 
Cc: ghi@ourdomain.com, 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="mime_boundry_multipart/related_c6644189126a16de6271c67af235ddd0x"
```

Comment: One additional thing when i take out header parameter from mail function it works fine. But i can't do it this way, beacuse this class is also being used by other modules and working fine. So something is wronng with header i think.

Comment: You have two conflicting Content-Type headers - which one is it? I'm guessing the multipart one is correct (and then I guess the first body part is text/html).

Comment: So you are saying that there should be only one content type?? which one should i keep?

Comment: Depends on the actual content, obviously. If the hints in my previous comment are insufficient, post a separate question, with a representative full meddage body (or at least full MIME headers for each part).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet it's complaining about the empty address in the Cc: field. Take out the trailing comma and you should be fine.